# Three.js texture looks clipped from right-side

Tags: three.js, textures, mesh

I have a mesh on top of a another mesh like below ( top mesh area is dark )

[image]

If I adding texture image like that;

```
var logoTexture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( logoPath );
mesh.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map:logoTexture } );
```

image looks corrupted ( clipped from right-side )

[image]

original image looks like;

[image]

I have no idea what's causing this problem, also image is 512x512 px.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe your texture aspect ratio does not match the geometry. You can adjust your geometry size and/or play with the texture positioning and stretching like this:

```
var map = logoTexture;

map.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
map.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;

map.offset.x = 0; // adjust as needed to move horizontally
map.offset.y = 0; // adjust as needed to move vertically

map.repeat.x = 1; // adjust as needed to stretch horizontally
map.repeat.y = 1; // adjust as needed to stretch vertically
```

Comment: Hi yaku, actually aspect ratios ( 1:1 ) are same. But couldn't understand exactly problem was solved like logoTexture.repeat.x = 1.3; my plane is square also texture is square. weird :)

Comment: how to remove the blank spaces between the repeating texture ?